Unable to CMAKE on Mac M2 - JNI was not found
I am trying to build SUMO on MAC M2, I am following the instructions from this source.
When I initiate cmake -B build, I get the following error:
-- CMAKE_BINARY_DIR: /Users/daspr/sumo/build
-- CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR: /Users/daspr/sumo
--
-- Platform:
--     Host: Darwin-23.4.0 arm64
--     Target: Darwin-23.4.0 arm64
--     CMake: 3.30.2
--     CMake generator: Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool: /usr/bin/make
--     Compiler: AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022
--
-- Found Python: /Users/daspr/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3.9
-- Brew detected: /opt/homebrew
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY)
-- Found Proj: /opt/homebrew/lib/libproj.dylib
-- Found Fox: -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fox/1.6.58/include/fox-1.6 -L/opt/homebrew/Cellar/fox/1.6.58/lib -lFOX-1.6 -lX11 -lXext -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lXft -lXcursor -lXrender -lXrandr -lXfixes -lXi -ldl -lpthread -ljpeg -lpng -ltiff -lz -lbz2 -lGLU -lGL
-- Could NOT find suitable FFmpeg.
-- Could NOT find JuPedSim! Skipping JuPedSim integration.
-- Found Java: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (found version "20.0.0") found components: Development
-- Found Java: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java (found version "20.0.0")
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 AWT)
CMake Warning at src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:151 (message):
  ENABLE_JAVA_BINDINGS is set but Java or JNI was not found.


xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 AWT)
CMake Warning at src/libtraci/CMakeLists.txt:110 (message):
  ENABLE_JAVA_BINDINGS is set but Java or JNI was not found.


-- Enabled features: Darwin-23.4.0 arm64 AppleClang 14.0.3.14030022 Release FMI Proj GUI FMT Intl SWIG Eigen GDAL OSG GL2PS
-- Configuring done (2.4s)
-- Generating done (0.9s)
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/daspr/sumo/build

I already have Java installed and echo $JAVA_HOME returns /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home.
Error faced:
xcode-select: error: tool 'xcodebuild' requires Xcode, but active developer directory '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools' is a command line tools instance
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 AWT)
    CMake Warning at src/libsumo/CMakeLists.txt:151 (message):
      ENABLE_JAVA_BINDINGS is set but Java or JNI was not found.

Please help.

This question is similar to: xcode-select active developer directory error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Hi @AndrewYim, while xcode-select error pops up here as well, my main concern is regarding JNI, and not xcode. If you want to, please help editing the question while keeping my central concern in line.

Oh, oops. I read the first line in your shortened error message and didn't read further. I assume you've already seen this? CMake could not find JNI

@AndrewYim Not for Mac, no accepted answers from Questioner.

There's an accepted answer here. See if those suggestions (and the ones from other answers) help - they might, despite the OS mismatch. (They also might not.)

@AndrewYim Doesn't work. JNI still not found.

You have not shown a JDK installed. Just a directory for the Java Applet browser plugin that has been deprecated for years. What java -version outputs?

@aled java -version gives : java version "20" 2023-03-21 Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 20+36-2344) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20+36-2344, mixed mode, sharing)

Your JAVA_HOME variable is not pointing to where the JDK is installed. Update it. But I would recommend to use a supported LTS version like 17 or 21. JDK 20 is a dead end.

@aled Changing JAVA_HOME didn't solve the problem, getting JDK 21 did. Thanks.

The xcode-select error is pretty pertinent to your situation but in a very roundabout way:
CMake runs xcodebuild --version to see if Xcode is 12.1 or newer. Depending on the answer it switches the internal CMAKE_FIND_FRAMEWORK to ONLY or NEVER. If the check fails (because xcodebuild -version does not return anything), it is set to the "ONLY" mode in which it will fail to find any files.
Add the following somewhere globally, before you call find_package for either Java or JNI to bypass the Xcode check:
set(XCODE_VERSION "15.0")

You will need to remove your build directory to get rid of any cached variables too.
EDIT: I reported this upstream.
